# PInvoke implementation of a C SDK function causing memory violation

Tags: c#

I am wanting to call a C DLL function from C#.  The function is described in the C include header file as:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef CMGO_BUILD_DLL
    #define CMGO_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define CMGO_DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define CMGO_API_CC __stdcall
#else
#define CMGO_DLL_API
#define CMGO_API_CC
#endif
typedef void* CMGO_DATACHANNEL_HANDLE;
CMGO_DLL_API int CMGO_API_CC cmgo_create_datachannel(const char* host, unsigned short port, CMGO_DATACHANNEL_HANDLE* handle);
```

---

A sample C file showing how to use the *cmgo_create_datachanell* DLL call to create the channel has this example usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int st;
    char address[] = "127.0.0.1";
    unsigned int port = 9800;

    CMGO_DATACHANNEL_HANDLE handle = NULL;
    struct CMGO_DATACHANNEL_READ_RESULT result;

    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));

    printf("Creating DataChannel [%s,%u] ...\n", address, port);

    st = cmgo_create_datachannel(address, port, &handle);
```

---

In C# I have written the following:

```
const string CarmenSDKDLL = "cmgocapi.dll";

[DllImport(CarmenSDKDLL, CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int cmgo_create_datachannel(string host, ushort port, IntPtr handle);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string ANPRServer = "127.0.0.1";
    ushort port = 9800;
    IntPtr iHandle = new IntPtr(0);

    int iResult = cmgo_create_datachannel(ANPRServer, port, iHandle);
}
```

When I run the C# code I get an exception

> System.AccessViolationException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory.

Can anyone pointer me in the right direction and explain what I have written incorrectly in the C# code?

Comment: Can you please provide typedefs for `CMGO_DLL_API` and `CMGO_API_CC`?

Comment: Your `string` is likely wrong type, but more importantly, it's very peculiar that you're passing in `new IntPtr(0);` - that's effectively a `nullptr` - is that a callback function? If so, this is very likely the source of problem. You'd need to call `GetLastError()` to really see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @CoolBots.  I originally had :

IntPtr iHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
int iResult = cmgo_create_datachannel(ANPRServer, port, iHandle);

but that caused a memory fault also

Comment: What happens if you remove the `const` in the C# definition of `ANPRServer`. Const strings in C# are just aliases for string literals. They may act weird

Comment: Do you declare your function STDCALL in your C, but CDECL in your C#. That can do very weird things

Comment: Thank you @Flydog57.  I have tried with, and without the calling convention specified `[DllImport(CarmenSDKDLL)` and the error is the same.  I have tried with and without the `const` string definition and the error is the same.  I have edited my post and shown the function being used in the sample C file that was provided with the SDK.

Comment: The biggest problem is that you need to marshal your string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-strings-using-pinvoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is you're passing the `handle` incorrectly - it is in fact a `void**`, not a `void*`; meaning, it's an `out IntPtr`, not an `IntPtr`

Change the calling code as follows:

```cs
const string CarmenSDKDLL = "cmgocapi.dll";

[DllImport(CarmenSDKDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
extern
static int cmgo_create_datachannel([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string host,
                                   ushort port,
                                   out IntPtr handle);
```

There are a few corrections in the above declaration:

- *Calling convention* - you need to match the declared calling convention, which is `__stdcall`, not `__cdecl`
- *String type* - C# strings are Unicode, not ANSI. You need to specify correct marshalling type.
- *`out` parameter* - Notice the declaration `typedef void* CMGO_DATACHANNEL_HANDLE;` - it's a `void*`; however, the function takes a *pointer* to that type - which is now a `void**`.

The *access violation exception* you are getting is specifically due to the last bullet point - the C function is trying to write to an invalid memory location.

*Calling code*:

```cs
const string ANPRServer = "127.0.0.1"; 
ushort port = 9800;

int errorCode = cmgo_create_datachannel(ANPRServer, port, out var handle);

if(errorCode == 0)
{
   // handle is a valid pointer of type IntPtr
}
```

In general, the errors that happen in the C functions called via P/Invoke may differ quite a bit from the exceptions you see in C# calling code. I recommend looking into [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=net-5.0) documentation and detailed example to improve the error handling in working with P/Invoke.

Answer (score 2):

The `handle` argument is obviously used to *return* a handle - you need to declare and call it with `ref`. Other than that, `string` arguments generally need some care - for example, by default, C# marshals strings as Unicode, and it seems that the DLL expects ANSI strings.  So my guess at the correct P/Invoke signature is

```
[DllImport(CarmenSDKDLL, CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int cmgo_create_datachannel([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string host, ushort port, ref IntPtr handle);
```